# Trying to get TextFormField data from another widget

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I am building an app that generates form fields from JSON data.
the Form widget is declared in the custom_form.dart

```
 child: Form(
    key: _globalKey,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Text("Register Form: "),
        SizedBox(
          height: 3,
        ),
        for (var i = 0; i < this.widget.widgetList.length; i++)
          generateWidgetFromType(this.widget.widgetList[i]),
```

I'm using that generateWidgetFrom Type to generate the widgets

```
Widget generateWidgetFromType(Mywidget mywidget) {
  switch (mywidget.type) {
    case "CheckBox":
      return GenerateCheckBox(mywidget);
    case "Input":
      return CustomGeneratedWidget(mywidget,
          onSaved: (value) => widget.test = value);
    case "DatePicker":
      return GenerateDatePicker(mywidget);
  }
  return Text("This type is not supported yet");
}
```

The TextFormField is declared in the CustomGeneratedWidget

```
  child: TextFormField(
      controller: textEditingController,
      obscureText: isPasswordField(this.widget.mywidget.key),
      keyboardType: customType(this.widget.mywidget.key),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: this.widget.mywidget.label,
          border: OutlineInputBorder()),
      validator: (value) {
```

I want to retrieve data from TextFormField in the CustomGeneratedWidget when I click on the Add button in the custom_form.dart

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to add a method called `getValue()` on to your `CustomGeneratedWidget` class:

```dart
class CustomGeneratedWidget extends Mywidget {
    TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();

    ...
    String getValue() {
      return textEditingController.text;
    }

    ...

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       ...
    }
}
```

I'm guessing, based on what you're building, that you'll want to eventually get data not just from `TextFormField` / `CustomGeneratedWidget` instances, but also instances of `GenerateCheckBox` and `GenerateDatePicker` as well.  With that being the case, if it were me, I would add an abstract method to `Mywidget` that you override in its subclasses, perhaps called `getValue()`.  So, Mywidget might look like:

```dart
abstract class Mywidget extends Widget {
    ...

    // this method is purposefully unimplemented, and is therefore an "abstract" method
    dynamic getValue();  

    ...
}
```

In your subclasses, such as CustomGeneratedWidget, you would "override" this method by redefining it / implementing it, and therefore making it "concrete":

```dart
class CustomGeneratedWidget extends Mywidget {
    TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
    ...

    @override
    String getValue() {
        return textEditingController.text;
    } 

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Container(
          child: TextFormField(
             controller: textEditingController
             ...
          )
       );
    }
}
```

Back in `custom_form.dart`, in your handler for your 'Add' button, you could go through the list of created `Mywidget` instances and call `getValue()` on each.